# Android: SharedPreferences from another class

Tags: android

I have this class where I save the data and where the method loadUsername() is.

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username;
    static String string_username;
    static SharedPreferences string_savepoint;
    SharedPreferences.Editor string_editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        username = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.username);

        //Speicher und Savepoint initialisieren
        string_savepoint = getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        string_editor = string_savepoint.edit();

        //Username laden
        username.setText(loadUsername());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Username speichern
        string_editor.putString("username", username.getText().toString());
        string_editor.commit();
    }

    protected static String loadUsername() {
        // Aus dem Speicher
        string_username = string_savepoint.getString("username", "Spieler");
        return string_username;
    }
```

Then I want to load the username in a another class.

```
Settings.loadUsername();
```

Actually this works but only if I have been in this class. If I start the app and go directly to the Activty where I wanna load the username I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.stefano.mathgame.Settings.loadUsername(Settings.java:43)
        at com.example.stefano.mathgame.Game.gameSuccess(Game.java:151)
        at com.example.stefano.mathgame.Game.onClick(Game.java:102)
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use this static method like this. Your string_savepoint will be initialized only when your activity Settings starts. If you try to use this static method without starting your activity you will get this Null pointer exception.

If you need to load the username from other code sections it will be best practice to create a some helper class to work with shared preferences, initialize it by passing it application context and than call its methods to save and load the username. This way the functionality of handling the persistence of the username will not be bind to an activity, which should be responsible for UI.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Could you please explain me it a bit more? Im thinking about to use AsyncTask.

Comment: It really depends on what your implementation is. If you need a Settings like screen to set there the username, password and other configurations I would suggest using native settings (see here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#SettingTypes) which uses shared preferences but you dont need to handle it directly. On the other hand if you have some user input or data you would like to save you can write your own wrapper to Preferences and use it by initalizing it and passing the data you want to save/load. Which one do you need?

Comment: Thank you Michael! For my App will be the option number 2 good. Actually I have 4 Activitys: Main, Game, Highscore and Settings. In Main are 3 buttons, one for each other activity. This means I need to somehow initialize Settings in the Main. I dont know how to do that... :)

Comment: If you call the screen "Settings" I think you should still go with the first option I gave you as this is the best practice. Make the user access the settings from action panel and you are good to go. If you still want to go with option number two, you can use third party libraries or do something similar to what you did but do not extend activity. For example, you can initialize your shared preferences in that class when onCreate of your application (not activity) is called and then load / save your data using static methods of that class.

Comment: I understand you now. :) I will try option nr 1. There is really no need to create a whole activity for just a few preferences! And by this the preferecens will be ready from begin!

BTW: I tryed to solve that problem with AsyncTask. First I called the Activity "Settings" and then "Game". Was successfull but still not good enough. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, good luck. If my answer helped please consider marking it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to avoid those kind of problem in future is to use [this library](https://github.com/Pixplicity/EasyPreferences).

```
compile 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.4'
```

All you need to do is to add a class to your project which extends Applications like this one below:

```
public class PrefsApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Initialize the Prefs class
        new Prefs.Builder()
                .setContext(this)
                .setMode(ContextWrapper.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .setPrefsName(getPackageName())
                .setUseDefaultSharedPreference(true)
                .build();
    }
}
```

and then you can simply read and write any value from the shared preferences without taking care of initialise it at the right moment (which caused your null point exception).

For read value from the shared preferences just do this:

```
Prefs.getString(key, default value)
```

and for saving values:

```
Prefs.putString(key, string)
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. This is a really good way to do this. I guess the library you mentioned is one that is not provided from Android normally? Actually I want to solve this problem by using classes that are already in.

Comment: True, the library that I mentioned is not default in android, but it is only a wrapper around the SharedPreferences class. In theory you could build your own wrapper if you don't want to use third party library. I don't know your motivations, however, there is nothing wrong to use libraries, you don't want to reinvent the wheel every time :-)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Actually this is my first real app and I want to have it "normal". I guess in future I will be of course be using the library you mentioned. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines

static SharedPreferences string_savepoint;
string_savepoint = getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

in those activities from where you wish to call Settings.loadUsername();